# Prove that there exists a polynomial $p(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ of degree 21 such that $p(5^{1/3}+7^{1/7})=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Prove that there exists a polynomial $p(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ of degree 21 such that $p(5^{1/3}+7^{1/7})=0$

It would be nice if I had some simple theorem to gaurentee that $\mathbb{Q}(5^{1/3}+7^{1/7})=\mathbb{Q}(5^{1/3},7^{1/7})$.

Other than that, I was going to set $u=(5^{1/3}+7^{1/7})$ and try to find a degree 21 polynomial and then prove it was irreducible. Anyone have any insight into this?

Comment: Note that $p$ is not required to be irreducible.  That makes things a lot easier.

Comment: Perhaps it might suffice that $\mathbb Q(5^{1/3}+7^{1/7}) \subset \mathbb Q(5^{1/3},7^{1/7})$.

Answer (score 3):

What we know for sure is that $5^{\frac{1}{3}}+7^{\frac{1}{7}}\in\mathbb{Q}(5^{\frac{1}{3}},7^{\frac{1}{7}})$ and hence $\mathbb{Q}(5^{\frac{1}{3}}+7^{\frac{1}{7}})\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(5^{\frac{1}{3}}, 7^{\frac{1}{7}})$. So the degree of the minimal polynomial of $5^{\frac{1}{3}}+7^{\frac{1}{7}}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ divides $21$. Can you finish from here?

Comment: So then, perhaps just take the minimal polynomial of $(5^{1/3}+7^{1/7})$, call it $p(x)$, and multiply by it a polynomial with the appropriate degree to a get a degree 21 polynomial in which (5^{1/3}+7^{1/7}) is a root. 

That work?

Comment: By what you wrote, wouldn't that mean the degree of the minimal polynomial IS 21? Did you mean to write $\mathbb{Q}(5^{1/3},7^{1/7})?$

Comment: Yes, that works. Actually we don't even need to know that the degree of the minimal polynomial divides $21$. Enough that it is at most $21$.

Comment: And yes, $[\mathbb{Q}(5^{\frac{1}{3}},7^{\frac{1}{7}}):\mathbb{Q}]=21$.